# MySQL returns "Table TABLE_NAME" doesn't exists when trying to insert data using JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have two mysql tables called `sub_acc` and `sub_loan`. I'm trying to insert data to insert data to these two tables, from first day of a month to current day.
I used `Calendar` class to get dates from first day of a month to current date and used `while` loop to insert data of each date.

I created four methods,

**Delete all data from two tables**

```
public void emptyTables() {
        try {
            String q1 = "TRUNCATE sub_loan";
            String q2 = "TRUNCATE sub_acc";

            conn c = new conn();
            Statement createStatement = c.getConnection().createStatement();
            createStatement.execute(q1);
            createStatement.execute(q2);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**Insert data to `sub_acc` table**

```
 public void insertAccountsData(String branch, String date) {
        String query1 = "INSERT IGNORE INTO \n"
                + "sub_acc(date, last_cash_in, last_cash_out, last_bank_in, last_bank_out, ho_funds, other_funds, funds_cash, funds_bank, diposit, withdrawal)\n"
                + " VALUES(\n"
                + "    DATE('" + date + "'),\n"
                + "    (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(cash),0)AS last_cash_in FROM accounts WHERE date = DATE(DATE('" + date + "')- INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND type = 'In'),\n"
                + "    (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(cash) ,0)AS last_cash_out FROM accounts WHERE date = DATE(DATE('" + date + "') - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND type = 'Out' ),\n"
                + "    (SELECT COAlESCE(SUM(diposit),0)AS last_bank_in FROM bank WHERE date = DATE(DATE('" + date + "') - INTERVAL 1 DAY)),\n"
                + "    (SELECT COAlESCE(SUM(withdraw),0)AS last_bank_out FROM bank WHERE date = DATE(DATE('" + date + "') - INTERVAL 1 DAY)),\n"
                + "    (SELECT COAlESCE(SUM(ho_funds),0)AS ho_funds FROM accounts WHERE date = DATE('" + date + "')),\n"
                + "    (SELECT COAlESCE(SUM(other_funds),0)AS other_funds FROM accounts WHERE date = DATE('" + date + "')),\n"
                + "    (SELECT COAlESCE(SUM(recieved),0)AS recieved_cash FROM funds WHERE date = DATE('" + date + "') AND branch_to = '" + branch + "' AND method = 'Cash'),\n"
                + "    (SELECT COAlESCE(SUM(recieved),0)AS recieved_bank  FROM funds WHERE date = DATE('" + date + "') AND branch_to = '" + branch + "' AND method = 'Bank'),\n"
                + "    (SELECT COAlESCE(SUM(diposit),0)AS diposit FROM bank WHERE date = DATE('" + date + "')),\n"
                + "    (SELECT COAlESCE(SUM(withdraw),0)AS withdraw FROM bank WHERE date = DATE('" + date + "')))";

        try {
            conn c = new conn();
            PreparedStatement ps = c.getConnection().prepareStatement(query1);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

**Insert data to `sub_loan` table**

```
public void insertLoanData(String date) {
        String query2 = "INSERT INTO sub_loan( date, interest, count, admision_fee, document_fee, insuarance, overdue_collection, completed_date)\n"
                + " SELECT DISTINCT \n"
                + " '" + date + "', \n"
                + "    COALESCE(l.interest,0),\n"
                + "    COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT l.idloan),0)AS count,\n"
                + "    COALESCE(l.admission_fee,0),\n"
                + "    COALESCE(l.document_fee,0),\n"
                + "    COALESCE(l.insuarance,0),\n"
                + " COALESCE((SELECT SUM(d1.overdue) FROM daily_collections d1 WHERE d1.loan_idloan = l.idloan),0)AS overdue_collection,\n"
                + "    ls.completed_date\n"
                + "    FROM loan l \n"
                + "    LEFT OUTER JOIN daily_collections d ON l.idloan = d.loan_idloan \n"
                + "    JOIN loan_session ls ON ls.loan_idloan = l.idloan\n"
                + "    WHERE ls.completed = 'Yes' AND ls.completed_date = '" + date + "'\n"
                + "    GROUP BY  ls.completed_date,l.interest";
        try {
            conn c = new conn();
            PreparedStatement ps = c.getConnection().prepareStatement(query2);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

**Iterate dates**

```
public void AddData(String branch, int year, int month) {

        Calendar tommorow = Calendar.getInstance();
        tommorow.setTime(new Date());
        tommorow.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        Date today = tommorow.getTime();

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month - 1);
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        int myMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);

        emptyTables();

        while (myMonth == cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {
            if (!cal.getTime().equals(today)) {
                String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(cal.getTime());
                insertAccountsData(branch, date);
                insertLoanData(date);
                cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Connection**

```
public class Connection {
    Connection con;
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(conn.class);
    public Connection() {
        if (con == null) {
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/microfinance", "root", "123");
            } catch (Exception e) {
               logger.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return con;
    }

}
```

but when I call `AddData()` method I get an exception:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'microfinance.sub_acc' doesn't exist

but when I execute these queries in workbench it's working fine. Also after I get this exception i checked my database and `sub_acc` and `sub_loan` tables not in db.

Comment: It can be an issue with the connection parameter please post them. Look in the parameters like database, schemas that you specified for connection parameters.

Comment: Thank you @KiranKumar. I added `connection` class

Answer (score 1):

I just found the issue. It's the table name. I changed `sub_acc` and `sub_loan` table names. Now it's working fine.